Does the subtraction of two sets require that the two sets are subsets of a larger set?
If I write A={dog, cat, cow} and B={cat,brown, blue, purple}, does A -  B= {dog,cow}  make sense by itself?  Or do I first need to declare a set U = {dog,cat,cow,brown,blue,purple} that encompasses both A and B?  I ask because most definitions of set subtraction don't mention such a universal set, but I'm wondering if this is assumed in the background.
I have a suspicion that the answer to this question involves something like the ZFC, which is beyond my knowledge.  So please have patience if the answer goes way beyond my simplistic set theory.

Given any two sets, there is always a set that contains their union, There is no such thing as a "universal set".  $A\setminus B$ is shorthand for ${a\in A \mid a\notin B}$, which is always a set whenever $A$ is a set.

I agree with Arturo. $A-B$ is the set of things in $A$ that aren't in $B$. This makes no reference to a larger set. If we have some larger set $U$, we can define complements $B^c$ to be the set of things in $U$ that aren't in $B$. Then one often sees $A-B=A\cap B^c$, but this is really a secondary result, not a definition.
